# convert exe file to a file executable in unix like environment

Tags: unix, exe

i have made a program using vc++ 2010 in c++ but the submission format is a file executable in UNIX like environment. Any suggestions what should be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get an appropriate UNIX system and recompile there. There's no practical way to "convert" a Windows executable to another platform.

Comment: does UNIX environment support all the classes of vc++ like maps strings vectors etc.?

Comment: @Aseem Dua: If you're using Linux, the GNU compiler supports C++03 probably more completely than VC++ 2010.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer 
will this help? where will the files I create and compile be stored?